# parse mongodb objects in angular

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I want to repeat a list of games in mongodb using angular.

controller:

```
   //get grabbit games
    $scope.getAllGames = function(){
        var q = $q.defer();

        $http.get('/public/views/grabbit/games.php?type=1').
          success(function(response) {
            if(!response.success){

            }else{
                    $scope.games = response
                    q.resolve($scope.games)
            }

          })

        return q.promise
    }

 $scope.promise = $scope.getAllGames();
    $scope.promise.then(function(response){
    //alert(data)
    $scope.games = response.data
    console.log($scope.games)
 })
```

Using angular and show the items in the db

```
<div class="col-lg-3 panel-info" data-ng-repeat="games in games">
                        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                            {{games.title}}
                        </div>
</div>
```

In the view I can see, it does repeat two  divs (which is the correct number of games in the db)... however the data is not showing.
I've tried a number of variations, then I read the $oid in mongo is what may be causing the problem.

What's the correct way to parse mongoDB objects in angular?

Comment: what does response.data look like?

Comment: it's just objects... nothing matching the data I want.

I switched to focusing more on how the data is sent back form games.php...

I tried a foreach loop... that actually works but it's only returning one of the games in the table and showing it twice...


  $games = $collectionGrabbit->find(array('completed'=>0));
  if($games!=""):

   foreach ($games as $doc) {
      $games = $doc;
   }
   //$games->getNext();
   $data['success'] = true;
   $data['games'] = $games;
  else:
   $data['success'] = false;
   $data['message'] = "no games";

  endif;

Comment: Repeat='games in games' is confusing. Should be 'game in games' then 'game.title'

Comment: {{games.games.title}} is the only thing that works... even with foreach... I'm only pulling one record out and angular is repeating that one record twice

Answer (score 0):

Got it working...

on my games.php

```
    $games = $collectionGrabbit->find(array('completed'=>0));

        $games = json_encode(iterator_to_array($games));

        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['games'] = $games;
```

in my controller

```
    //get grabbit games
    $scope.getAllGames = function(){
        var q = $q.defer();

        $http.get('/public/views/grabbit/games.php?type=1').
          success(function(response) {
            if(!response.success){

            }else{
                    $scope.list = response;
                    q.resolve($scope.list)
            }

          })

        return q.promise
    }

$scope.promise = $scope.getAllGames();
    $scope.promise.then(function(data){


        //$scope.games = angular.fromJson(data)
        $scope.games = angular.fromJson(data.games);
                console.log($scope.games)
})
```